# Tracking links with Omniture

Tags: asp.net, adobe-analytics

I want to track the clicks on few images on a web page. For this, I have done below:

1. Included reference to `s_code.js` on the page
2. Attached image click event using jQuery

   ```
   $(".imgClose").click(function () { track_rejectOffer(this); });
   ```
3. Wrote function code in global js file

   ```
   function track_rejectOffer(obj) {
     var s = s_gi(s_account);
     s.linkTrackVars = "eVar52,events";
     s.linkTrackEvents = "event80";
     s.events = "event80";
     s.eVar52 = "My Offers Page";
     s.tl(obj, 'o', obj.title);
   }
   ```

However, when I run the website and click on the link, I do not observe the `s.eVar52` set in the page source. I debugged the code using chrome and found that above function is executed line by line.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: do you see the `s.tl` call being made at all? also, you have `event13` listed in `s.linkTrackEvents` but `event80` listed in `s.events`

Comment: also, what do you mean you do not see `s.eVar52` set in the page source? you mean like rightclick > viewsource? firstly your code shows you are setting it with a static value "Populate with the pagename the link was clicked on". But even if you e.g. change it to `location.href' or something it will just show `location.href` in the viewsource. you need to look at what is actually being sent to adobe with an addon like digitalpulse, firebug, charles proxy, etc.

Comment: one final thing is that the first argument of `s.tl` will not work properly unless the object has an `.href` property. If it doesn't, then you need to use (boolean) `true` as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks Crayon.. I will correct the code and check again if works. And yes, I meant the right click > page source.

Comment: I have corrected the code and it is executed as well. However, I don't see the variables and other things set when I check the page source by right clicking.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what it is you are trying to do. `Rightclick > Viewsource` only shows what the server outputs to the browser. So the only point of looking at that is if you are dynamically outputting values from server-side code.

Comment: True, that means my Omniture code might be working already even though it is not visible in page source?

Comment: as i said you need to look at the actual request being made to omniture. https://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/meet-the-new-digitalpulse-debugger/

Comment: Page source is not the correct place where you are looking for.Install HTTP fox debugger.Check the image request in mozilla HTTPfox,you will find the required variable.

Comment: Check out the forum too ! The forum is a great place to bounce ideas off other users and get live feedback.  http://adobe.ly/1juTbTO